# Codeigniter index() function not being called

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am fairly new working with codeigniter. I am currently trying to setup an existing codeigniter project but Main controller's index() method is not being called.
I have gone through almost all related question posted here @ stackoverflow but nothing seems to work for me.

below is my code:

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Front_main');
    $this->load->model('Front_expertweb');
}

public function index(){
    echo 'im here';
    ....
}
....
}
```

**EDIT**

.htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
#<IfModule mod_filter.c>
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/*
#</IfModule>
```

config.php

`$config['index_page'] = ''
$config['base_url'] = ''`

PHP version: 5.+

Codeigniter: 2.+

would really appreciate if you could route me in the ride direction.

much appreciated.

Comment: `__construct()`  get called?

Comment: @FastSnail yeah.. its called

Comment: what is the url you typed?index won't get called if you request other controller functions

Comment: @FastSnail on localhost
http://localhost/app-name

Comment: What is error when you run project in broswer?

Comment: @HamzaZafeer no errors logged what so ever.. thats bit confusing for me..

Comment: Is your configuration is right? Follow Documentation https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/index.html and https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html

Comment: How are you calling function?? `index()` will not be called everytime... If you are calling like `path_to_project/main`, then `index()` will be executed..

Comment: Did you tried to comment `$this->load->model('Front_main');` and `$this->load->model('Front_expertweb');`

Comment: @hanishsingla yes, same issue. Even Front_main's constructor is also called

Comment: ok. . whats the url you are trying to access? . .and is there any error?

Comment: localhost/appName and no there are no errors logged

Comment: try `http://localhost/yourproject/index.php/main` if you can get it that way then you need a new htaccess make sure your base url is set though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bummmmp!
So there was NOTHING wrong with the code. Previous developer had saved configuration URL in database without any documentation.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
   // $this->load->model('Front_main');
   // $this->load->model('Front_expertweb');
}

public function index(){
    echo 'im here';
    ....
}
....
}
```

**config.php**

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php'
$config['base_url'] = 'your project foldername'
```

Comment: please explain what you did there.
PS: i did tried this earlier but it didnt help